# In the space of probability distributions, is the set of discrete distributions dense?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, metric-spaces

Is the following true:

> In the space of probability distributions, the set of discrete  distributions is dense with regard to the Lévy metric.

Can someone point me to any reference on this subject?

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 3):

There is a more general theorem in Parthasarathy's *Probability measures on metric spaces* on page 66:

> Let $X$ be a separable metric space and $E\subset X$ dense in $X$. Then the set of all measures whose supports are finite subsets of $E$ is dense in $U(X)$.

In the book "measure" means probability measure, and $U(X)$ is the space of all probability measures.

Comment: It's theorem 6.3 in the 1967 edition.