# How to show that the space of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ is separable under Lévy metric

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence, separable-spaces

The Lévy metric between distribution functions $F$ and $G$ is given by:

$$\rho(F,G) = \inf\left\{\epsilon : F(x-\epsilon)-\epsilon\leq G(x)\leq F(x+\epsilon)+\epsilon\right\}.$$

Another way to write this is:

$$\rho(F,G) = \inf\left\{\epsilon : F(x)\leq G(x+\epsilon)+\epsilon ; G(x)\leq F(x+\epsilon)+\epsilon\right\}.$$

I also know that $\rho(F_n,F)\rightarrow 0 \iff F_n\rightarrow F$ weakly.

> The question is to show that the space of probability measures, say $P$, on $\mathbb{R}$ is separable with the Lévy metric.

In other words, have to show $\exists$  a countable dense subset of $P$. I was thinking about discretizing the distribution function of any given probability measure, along $x$, and estimate the value in an interval by $\sup\{q: q\leq F(x), q\in Q\}$ i.e. approximating $F(x)$ by a rational number.

But I am not sure as to how use Lévy metric to show that in any $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $F$, $\exists F_Q$. Thanks and appreciate a hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already know that $\varrho$-convergence is equivalent to weak convergence, it suffices to find a countable family $Q$ of probability measures such that for any probability measure $\mathbb{P} \in P$ there exists a sequence $(\mathbb{P}_{\ell})_{\ell \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq Q$ with $\mathbb{P}_{\ell} \to \mathbb{P}$ weakly. We will show that

$$Q := \left\{ \sum_{k=1}^K q_k \delta_{y_k}; y_k \in \mathbb{Q}, q_k \in \mathbb{Q}, K \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$

does the job. For the proof I will use the fact that $\mathbb{P}_{\ell}$ converges weakly to $\mathbb{P}$ if and only if $\int f \, d\mathbb{P}_{\ell} \to \int f \, d\mathbb{P}$ for any uniformly continuous bounded function $f$.

---

**Construction of the approximating sequence:** Fix $\mathbb{P} \in P$. For $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\ell \geq 1$ set

$$I_k^{\ell} := [k2^{-\ell}, (k+1) 2^{-\ell}) \quad \text{and} \quad a_k^{\ell} := \mathbb{P}(I_k^{\ell}).$$

Since $\mathbb{P}$ is a probability measure (hence a finite measure) we can choose $N_{\ell} \in \mathbb{N}$ sufficiently large such that

$$\mathbb{P} \left( K_{\ell}^c \right) \leq \frac{1}{\ell} \quad \text{for} \, \, K_{\ell} := \bigcup_{k=-N_{\ell}}^{N_{\ell}} I_{k}^{\ell}. \tag{1}$$

For $k \in \{-N_{\ell},\ldots,N_{\ell}\}$ we choose $q_k^{\ell} \in \mathbb{Q}$, such that $q_k^{\ell} \leq a_k^{\ell}$ and $$|q_k^{\ell}-a_k^{\ell}| \leq \frac{1}{2 \ell N_{\ell}} \tag{2}$$ and we set $$\mathbb{P}_{\ell} :=(1-r^{\ell}) \delta_0+ \sum_{k=-N_{\ell}}^{N_{\ell}} q_k^{\ell} \delta_{k 2^{-\ell}}$$ where $r^{\ell} := \sum_{k=-N_{\ell}}^{N_{\ell}} q_{k}^{\ell}$. Since $q_k^{\ell} \leq a_k^{\ell}$, we have $r^{\ell} \leq 1$, and it follows easily that each $\mathbb{P}_{\ell}$ is a probability measure.

**Proof of the weak convergence:** Fix $\epsilon>0$ and a uniformly continuous bounded function $f$. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, we can choose $L \geq 1$ sufficiently large such that

$$|x-y| \leq 2^{-L} \implies |f(x)-f(y)| \leq \epsilon. \tag{3}$$

Using that

\begin{align*}\int f \, d\mathbb{P}_{\ell}- \int f \, d\mathbb{P} &= -\int_{K_{\ell}^c} f \, d\mathbb{P} + (1-r^{\ell}) f(0) - \sum_{k=-N_{\ell}}^{N_{\ell}} \int_{I_k^{\ell}} (f(x)-f(k2^{-\ell})) \, d\mathbb{P}(x) \\ &\quad + \sum_{k=-N_{\ell}}^{N_{\ell}} (q_k^{\ell}-a_k^{\ell}) f(k 2^{-\ell}) \end{align*}

it follows from the boundedness of $f$ and (3) that

$$\left| \int f \, d\mathbb{P}_{\ell}- \int f \, d\mathbb{P}\right| \leq \|f\|_{\infty} \left[ \mathbb{P}(K_{\ell}^c) + (1-r^{\ell}) \right] + \epsilon \underbrace{\mathbb{P}(K_{\ell})}_{\leq 1} + \|f\|_{\infty} \sum_{k=-N_{\ell}}^{N_{\ell}} |q_k^{\ell}-a_k^{\ell}|$$ for all $\ell \geq L$. Because of $(2)$ we have

$$\sum_{k=-N_{\ell}}^{N_{\ell}} |q_k^{\ell}-a_k^{\ell}| \leq \frac{1}{\ell},$$

and on the other hand it is not difficult to see that $r_{\ell} \to 1$ as $\ell \to \infty$, i.e. $|r^{\ell}-1| \leq \epsilon$ for $\ell$ sufficiently large. As, by construction, $\mathbb{P}(K^c_{\ell}) \leq 1/\ell$ we conclude that

$$\left| \int f \, d\mathbb{P}_{\ell}- \int f \, d\mathbb{P}\right| \leq \|f\|_{\infty} \left( \frac{2}{\ell}+\epsilon \right) + \epsilon$$

for all $\ell$ sufficiently large which clearly proves $\int f \, d\mathbb{P}_{\ell} \to \int f \, d\mathbb{P}$ as $\ell \to \infty$.

Comment: A few questions. Q1) I have trouble seeing $\mathbb{P}_l$ as a prob measure. $\mathbb{P}_l := (1-r_l)\delta _{0}+\sum_{-N_l}^{N_l}q_{l}^{k}\delta_{k2^{-l}}$ The support of $\mathbb{P}_l$ is $k2^{-l}$. May I know what $\mathbb{P}_l(k)$ is and how $\mathbb{P}_l$ sums to 1? I am confused with $\delta_k$ inside the sum.

Comment: @manifolded $\delta_x$ denotes the Dirac measure at $x$, i.e.$$\delta_x(B) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \in B, \\ 0, & x \notin B. \end{cases}$$ You really just need to use this definition and the definition of $r_{\ell}$ in order to show that $\mathbb{P}_{\ell}$ is a probability measure..

Comment: @manifolded If you prefer, you can use $$\delta_x(B) = 1_{B}(x)$$ as a definition of the Dirac measure, sure. The support is $\{k 2^{-\ell};k=-N_{\ell},\ldots, N_{\ell}\}$ as you can see from the very definition of $\mathbb{P}_{\ell}$.

Comment: Would $\mathbb{P}_l(0) = (1-r_l)\delta_{0} + \sum_{k=-N_l}^{k=-1}q_k^{l}\delta_{k2^{-l}} + \sum_{k=1}^{k=N_l}q_k^{l}\delta_{k2^{-l}} + q_{0}^{l}\delta_{0}$?

Comment: @manifolded I don't understand your question. You might want to notice that $\mathbb{P}_{\ell}(0)$ doesn't make any sense; $\mathbb{P}_{\ell}(A)$ is only well-defined for sets and not for points. If you like you can write the definition of the measure equivalently as $$\mathbb{P}_{\ell}(B) = (1-r_{\ell}) \delta_0(B) + \sum_{k=-N_{\ell}}^{-1} q_k^{\ell} \delta_{k 2^{-\ell}}(B) + \sum_{k=1}^{N_{\ell}} q_k^{\ell} \delta_{k 2^{-\ell}}(B) + q_0^{\ell} \delta_0(B)$$ for any measurable set $B$....although I don't see why one would want to split up the sum this way...

Comment: For a fixed $l$, if the support of $\mathbb{P}_l$ is $\{k2^{-l}| k = -N_{l},..,N_{l}\}$, then isn't $\mathbb{P}_l$ a discrete measure where $\mathbb{P}_l$ is defined for $k2^{-l}$ including when $k=0$? Sorry, for the whole confusion.

Comment: @manifolded It is a discrete measure, yes. Because of this, you can use $\mathbb{P}(k2^{-\ell})$ as a short-hand for $\mathbb{P}_{\ell}(\{k2^{-\ell}\})$ but in my oppinion that's not a particularly good idea.

Comment: Understood $\mathbb{P}_l$ now. We place $q_k^{l}$ mass at $k2^{-l}$ and hence $\sum_{k}\mathbb{P}_l(\{k2^{-l}\}) = \sum_{k=-N_l}^{-1}q_k^{l}+\sum_{k=1}^{N_l}q_k^{l}+q_0^{l}+1-r^{l} = 1$.

Comment: Last question. Why is $\int fdP_l - \int fdP = -\int_{K_l^{c}} fdP + (1-r^l)f(0) - \sum_{k=-N_l }^{N_l }\int_{I_k^{l}}(f(x)-f(k2^{-l}))dP(x) + \sum_{k=-N_l}^{N_l}(q_k^{l}-a_k^{l})f(k2^{-l})$

Comment: I can see $$\int fdP_l - \int fdP = \int_{K_l^{c}} fdP_l - \int_{K_l^{c}} fdP +  \int_{K_l} fdP_l - \int_{K_l} fdP$$ and probably $$\int_{K_l} fdP_{l} = (1-r^l)f(0) + \sum_{k=-N_l}^{N_l}(q_k^{l}-a_k^{l})f(k2^{-l})$$ but can't understand why $$\int_{K_l^{c}}fdP_{l}-\int_{K_l}fdP = \sum_{k=-N_l }^{N_l }\int_{I_k^{l}}(f(k2^{-l})-f(x))dP(x)$$? I see why integral over $K_l$ can be written as a sum of integrals but one integral is over $K_l^{c}$ and the other over $K_l$ which is confusing me.

Comment: @manifolded First of all, $\mathbb{P}_l(K_l^c)=0$ (by the definition of $K_l$ and $P_k^l$) and so $\int_{K_l^c} f \, dP_l=0$. The second equation in your last comment is wrong, it should read $$\int_{K_l} f \, dP_l = (1-r^l) f(0) + \sum_k q_k^{\ell} f(k2^{-l}).$$ To prove the identity from my answer you have to use that $$\int_{I_k^l} f(k2^{-l}) \, dP = a_{k}^l f(k2^{-l})$$ (by the definition of $a_k^l$) and sum this over $k$ to get $$\sum_k a_k^l f(k2^{-l}) = \sum_k \int_{I_k^l} f(k2^{-l}) \, dP.$$

Comment: You can find a generalization of this in Prokhorov original paper.

Comment: Understood the construction of the approximant. Is there another way of proving weak convergence??