# Weak convergence of discrete probability measures in separable metric space

Tags: measure-theory, weak-convergence

Suppose $P$ is a Borel probability measure on the separable metric space $(S,\rho)$. Suppose $\{x_1,x_2,\cdots\}$ is a countable dense subset of $S$. Since $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} B\left(x_i,\dfrac{1}{n}\right)=S$, there exist, for each $n$, disjoint Borel measurable sets $A_1,\cdots,A_{k_n}$ with $P(\cup_{i=1}^{k_n}A_i)>1-\dfrac{1}{n}$.

We pick rational numbers $0\leq r_{1,n},\cdots,r_{k_n,n}\leq1$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{k_n}|P(A_i)-r_{i,n}|<\dfrac{1}{n}$. Letting $\alpha_n=\sum_{i=1}^{k_n}r_{i,n}$ we have $1-\dfrac{2}{n}<\alpha_n<1-\dfrac{1}{n}$.

Now we define Borel probability measure $P_n$ by $P_n(\{x_i\})=\dfrac{r_{i,n}}{\alpha_n}$ for $1\leq i\leq k_n$. Then I intend to show $P_n\implies P$.

I tried to take a bounded continuous $f$ and show that $P_n(f)\to P(f)$ but can't really do it. Ideally I would like to check one of the conditionsof weak convergence as given in Portmanteau theorem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your third sentence.  The existence of disjoint Borel sets $A_1, \dots, A_{k_n}$ with $P(\bigcup_{i=1}^{k_n} A_i) > 1-1/n$ is trivial, just take $A_1 = S$ and $A_2 = \dots = \emptyset$.  Did you want to assert some different conditions?  From the context, did you want them to be balls of radius less than $1/n$?

Comment: Or, maybe you just wanted each one to be a set of diameter less than $1/n$, not necessarily a ball (that would make it hard to take them disjoint).

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3117713/36150); it's a  bit different framework but perhaps you can get some ideas what to do.

Comment: Nothing, just take those balls and disjointify them to get Borel sets $A_i$...I don't need $A_i$ to be balls.

Comment: Nothing, just take those balls and disjointify them to get Borel sets $A_i$...I don't need $A_i$ to be balls.

Comment: Is the metrizable and separable space also locally compact? If so, you can assume $f$ to have compact support as well and then use Heine-Cantor to show it is uniformly continuous, that will be a of help.