# Does every connected compact metric space have a unique always attainable average distance?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces, average

**Problem statement**

Let $(X,d)$ be a connected compact metric space. Then does there always exist a unique value $\alpha\geq0$ with the following property?

For every $x_1,\ldots,x_k\in X$ there exists $x\in X$ such that the average distance from $x$ to $x_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,k$ is exactly $\alpha$.

**Proof of existence**

The following proves such a value always exists, so the main question is whether it is unique.

For $v\in X^n$, define
\begin{align*}
f_v(x)&:=\frac{d(x,v_1)+\ldots+d(x,v_n)}n,
\\a(v)&:=\min_{x\in X}f_v(x),
\\b(v)&:=\max_{x\in X}f_v(x).
\end{align*}
Because $X$ is compact and $f_v$ is continuous, the image of $f_v$ is also compact and thus indeed has a minimum and a maximum.

Let $v\in X^n$ and $w\in X^m$. We have $$a(w)\leq\frac{f_w(v_1)+\ldots+f_w(v_n)}n=\frac{f_v(w_1)+\ldots+f_v(w_m)}m\leq b(v).$$ It follows that there exists a supremum $\alpha$ of $a$ and an infimum $\beta$ of $b$, and that we have $\alpha\leq\beta$.

Let $v\in X^n$, so we have $a(v)\leq\alpha\leq\beta\leq b(v)$. Since $X$ is connected, the image of $f_v$ is connected, so since it contains $a(v)$ and $b(v)$, it also contains $[a(v),b(v)]$. It follows that there exists $x\in X$ such that $f_v(x)=\alpha$.

Note that uniqueness is thus equivalent with stating that $\alpha=\beta$ in the above proof.

**Looking for counterexamples**

The most straight forward connected compact metric spaces that come to mind are $[0,1]^n$. Let $v(t):=(t,\ldots,t)$. We have $$a(v(0),v(1))=b(v(1/2))=\sqrt{n}/2=\alpha=\beta.$$

Consider a regular $n$-gon $P_1,\ldots,P_n$ with center $O$. We have $$a(P_1,\ldots,P_n)=b(O)=|P_1O|=\alpha=\beta.$$

If we have the boundary of a unit square $ABCD$, let $E,F,G,H$ be the centers of the edges. We have $$a(A,B,C,D)=b(E,F,G,H)=\frac14(1+\sqrt5)=\alpha=\beta.$$

If we have the unit circle, let $v_n$ denote $n$ evenly spaced points. We have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a(v_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}b(v_n)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|1-e^{i\theta}|\ \mbox{d}\theta=\frac4\pi=\alpha=\beta,$$ so we can essentially approximate any measure, in this case giving us the average distance between two points on a circle.

Consider an arbitrary acute triangle $ABC$ with circumcenter $O$. Note that $b(O)=|AO|$. Since we can approximate any measure, we can introduce weights $w_A,w_B,w_C$. Fixing $w_A$, we find unique values of $w_B,w_C$ such that $f_{w_AA,w_BB,w_CC}(P)$ has gradient $0$ at $P=O$, which gives $$a(w_AA,w_BB,w_CC)=b(O)=|AO|=\alpha=\beta.$$

So it seems like $\alpha=\beta$ always holds, but I can not come up with a proof. I even tried some really ugly non-symmetric non-convex sets, and some metric spaces which are not subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and while it becomes more work each time, I always end up proving $\alpha=\beta$. All proofs rely on constructing measures $\mu,\nu$ such that $a(\mu)=b(\nu)$, but I can not figure out the bigger picture of what these measures are in general. I would not even know how to define measures in arbitrary metric spaces to begin with.

**Edit: A measure theory approach**

We can phrase the question in terms of probability measures as follows.

Let $(X,d)$ be a connected compact metric space with Borel $\sigma$-algebra $B(X)$. Then does there always exist a unique value $\alpha\geq0$ with the following property?

For every probability measure $P$ on $(X,B(X))$, there exists $x\in X$, such that $\mathbb{E}_{y\sim P}(d(x,y))=\alpha$.

The existence proof is completely analogous if we use $f_P(x):=\mathbb{E}_{y\sim P}(d(x,y))$, for $P$ a probability measure on $(X,B(X))$, because $f_P$ is still continuous. Indeed, $f_P$ has Lipschitz constant $1$.

Equivalence with the finite average approach follows from [discrete probability measures are dense in separable metric spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1310735/in-the-space-of-probability-distributions-is-the-set-of-discrete-distributions). Indeed, since $X$ is compact, it is separable.

**Optimal probability measures**

The generalization to arbitrary probability measures allows us to do the following.

Since the set of probability measures $P$ on $(X,B(X))$ is sequentially compact, see [Theorem 10.2](https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/Charles.Walkden/ergodic-theory/lecture10.pdf), there exist probabability measures $P_a$ and $P_b$ on $(X,B(X))$ such that $a(P_a)=\alpha$ and $b(P_b)=\beta$.

*Claim:* We have $\alpha=\beta$ if, and only if, we have $f_{P_a}(x)=\alpha$ for all $x\in\mbox{supp}(P_b)$, and vice versa.

*Proof:* For the left implication, since $X$ is strongly Lindelöf, we have $$\alpha=\mathbb{E}_{x\sim P_b}(f_{P_a}(x))=\mathbb{E}_{x\sim P_a}(f_{P_b}(x))=\beta.$$ For the right implication, note that, if $f_{P_a}(x)>\alpha$ for some $x\in\mbox{supp}(P_b)$, then $$\alpha<\mathbb{E}_{x\sim P_b}(f_{P_a}(x))=\mathbb{E}_{x\sim P_a}(f_{P_b}(x))\leq\beta.$$

Comment: I find this problem incredibly fascinating. It would strike me as a surprise if uniqueness were true.

Comment: If $\alpha\lt\beta$, not only does uniqueness fail, but it fails very badly with a continuum of counterexamples. This order of magnitude prove useful, using set theoretic trickery, to prove such a continuum of counter examples cannot exist. Just a thought. +1 for the intriguing question and the existence proof

Comment: Isn't $\beta$ just radius of our space (minimal $r$ s.t. our space fits into a ball of radius $r$)?

Comment: This is the idea I had, but the key claim doesn’t sound easy to show. Let  $\epsilon >0$. There are $x_1,\ldots,x_s \in X$ such that $\min_{1 \leq i \leq s}\,d(x_i,\cdot) \leq \epsilon/4$. Then, for any $v \in X^n$, $f_v(x)$ is at distance at most $\epsilon/4$ from one of the $f_v(x_i)$. Thus, $b(v)-a(v) \leq \epsilon/2+\max_{1 \leq i,j \leq s}{f_v(x_j)-f_v(x_i)}$. Now, “morally”, if we draw the $v_i$ iid according to some probability measure $\mu$, SLLN bounds the RHS with probability one, as long as $\int{d(x_i,y)d\mu(y)}$ doesn’t depend on $i$. I’m not sure whether $\mu$ exists in general.

Comment: If you consider the average _quadratic_ distance instead, I think I can show that for convex sets $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ we have $\tilde\alpha=\tilde\beta=r$, where $r$ is the radius of $X$ as suggested by @mihaild and $\tilde\alpha,\tilde\beta$ are the analogues for the quadratic distance. This is based on the fact that the barycenter of some points is the point that infimizes the average quadratic distance from them. (More in general, this should work whenever the center of a minimal ball containing $X$ is also contained in $X$). However this is purely Euclidean

Comment: @mihaild I think this is correct for convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. A proof similar to that I gave for arbitrary acute triangles should apply in general. However, this is not true for the boundary of a square or a circle, as shown in the examples I gave.

Comment: I made an edit formalizing the ideas about measure, confirming my intuition that there always exist probability measures $P_a$ and $P_b$ such that $a(P_a)=\alpha$ and $b(P_b)=\beta$. The claim about supports also formalizes the idea that $P_b$ has to be near the "middle" and $P_a$ has to be as far as possible from the "middle".

Comment: After the reformulation with measures, I think that equality follows simply from a minimax theorem. I'll try to write something up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that indeed $\alpha=\beta$.

First let us reformulate the problem making also the optimal point $x$ a measure. By definition,
$$
a(\mu)=\inf_{x\in X}\int_X d(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(y).
$$
Let us introduce
$$
A(\mu):=\inf_{\nu\in\mathcal{P}(X)}\int_X\int_X d(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(y)\,\mathrm{d}\nu(x).
$$
**Claim.** $A(\mu)=a(\mu)$ for every $\mu\in\mathcal{P}(X)$.

**Proof.** On one hand it is clear that $A(\mu)\le a(\mu)$ by choosing $\nu=\delta_{x_0}$, with $x_0$ optimal point for $a(\mu)$.

On the other hand, let $\mu\in\mathcal{P}(X)$ be fixed and let $\nu$ be optimal for $A(\mu)$. First, for every $E\subseteq X$ we must have
$$
\int_X\int_X d(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(y)\,\mathrm{d}(\nu\llcorner E)(x)=A(\mu)\nu(E),
$$
otherwise either $\frac{1}{\nu(E)}\nu\llcorner E$ or $\frac{1}{\nu(E^c)}\nu\llcorner E^c$ would be a better competitor (here $\nu\llcorner E\,(B):=\nu(E\cap B)$ denotes the restriction of $\nu$ to $E$). It follows that for every $E\subseteq X$ with $\nu(E)> 0$
$$
\frac{1}{\nu(E)}\int_{x\in E} \int_{y\in X}d(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(y)\,\mathrm{d}\nu(x)=A(\mu)
$$
and by standard arguments it follows that the function $x\mapsto \int d(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(y)$ is constant $\nu$-a.e., equal to $A(\mu)$. Then, for $\nu$-a.e. point $x_0$, $\tilde\nu:=\delta_{x_0}$ would still be an optimal competitor for $A(\mu)$, and therefore $x_0$ would be optimal for $a(\mu)$ (with the same value). $\blacksquare$

With a similar argument, $b(\mu)$ equals
$$
B(\mu):=\sup_{\nu\in\mathcal{P}(X)}\int_X \int_X d(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(y)\,\mathrm{d}\nu(x).
$$

To prove $\alpha=\beta$ we are thus reduced to prove (I exchanged $\mu$ and $\nu$ by symmetry)
$$
\sup_{\mu\in\mathcal{P}(X)}\inf_{\nu\in\mathcal{P}(X)}\int_X\int_X d(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(y)\,\mathrm{d}\nu(x)=\inf_{\nu\in\mathcal{P}(X)}\sup_{\mu\in\mathcal{P}(X)}\int_X\int_X d(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(y)\,\mathrm{d}\nu(x).
$$
This equality follows from a version of the [minimax theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_theorem) *, after observing that the function
$$
\mathcal{P}(X)\times\mathcal{P}(X)\ni(\mu,\nu)\mapsto \int_X\int_X d(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(y)\,\mathrm{d}\nu(x)
$$
is bilinear (and thus convex in one variable and concave in the other).

*For instance, look at: Ky Fan, Minimax Theorems. *Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences of the United States of America* Vol. 39, No. 1 (Jan. 15, 1953), pp. 42-47.
There is probably a simpler reference but this is the first I could find that works for infinite-dimensional spaces.

Comment: @SmileyCraft Let me add again that I find it fascinating that equality holds (unless someone can spot a mistake above). This gives a "typical length" value to any compact metric space in a way that I haven't encountered anywhere else. Very interesting problem, how did you come up with it?

Comment: Amazing! So just some clarifications. Since $X$ and $\mathcal{P}(X)$ are compact, all infima and suprema can be replaced with minima and maxima, correct? In your proof of the claim, it seems you already use this fact anyways. Furthermore, do I understand correctly that the connectedness of $X$ is not used in the proof that $\alpha=\beta$? For example, for $X=[0,1]\cup[2,3]$, we have $a(\{0,3\})=b(\{0,3\})=\frac32=\alpha=\beta$, but there exists no $x\in X$ with $f_{\{0\}}(x)=\frac32$. So that is pretty interesting how $\alpha=\beta$ still holds.

Comment: @SmileyCraft Yes, all infima and suprema are attained by compactness ( I wrote them as $\inf$ and $\sup$ only out of habit). You are correct that this does not use connectedness of the space, and I find your simple example enlightening.

Comment: I was trying to come up with an example of a non-compact space $X$ such that $\alpha<\beta$, but even in this generality I am not able to find any examples. So I made this into a follow up question :) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4473618/does-every-metric-space-have-a-minimax-radius

Comment: Looking at the answer of the other question it appears that this is a case where knowing the magic word "rendevouz number" can open up lots of search hits. I even found a previous question on mathoverflow: [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314382/function-as-sum-of-distances-over-a-connected-compact-metric-space).

Answer (score 1):

Nice problem! Here are some thoughts which are too long for a comment.

One natural approach is to try to construct measures $\mu$ such that $b(\mu)-a(\mu)$ is arbitrarily small, as suggested by Aphelli in the comments.
Unfortunately this is not always possible; consider for example the following tripod graph, endowed with the graph metric such that each edge has length $1$.[image]

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on this space. Without loss of generality, we can assume that the segment $AO$ (with $A$ included but $O$ excluded) has measure $\le \frac{1}{3}$. Then $f_\mu(A)\ge f_\mu(O)+\frac{1}{3}$, so $b(\mu)-a(\mu)\ge \frac{1}{3}$.

This is not a counterexample to the OP's question, however, since we have $a(A,B,C)=b(O)=1$.

Comment: I had the same initial idea, because the first spaces I tried were $[0,1]$ and a circle, for which this was true. However, these spaces appear to be quite exceptional with this property, as none of the other examples i have tried share this property. Nice proof, though. Although, I think the measure theory edit I just made allows for a more straight forward proof. Since $P_b=O$ suffices, we have $\mbox{supp}(P_a)\subset\{A,B,C\}$.