# Does every metric space have a minimax radius?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces, average

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space with $\mathcal{P}(X)$ the space of probability measures on its Borel $\sigma$-algebra. For $\mu,\nu\in\mathcal{P}(X)$, define
\begin{align*}
d(\mu,\nu)&:=\int_X\int_Xd(x,y)\ \mbox{d}\mu(x)\ \mbox{d}\nu(y),
\\A(\mu)&:=\inf_{\nu\in\mathcal{P}(X)}d(\mu,\nu),
\\B(\nu)&:=\sup_{\mu\in\mathcal{P}(X)}d(\mu,\nu),
\\\alpha&:=\sup_{\mu\in\mathcal{P}(X)}A(\mu),
\\\beta&:=\inf_{\nu\in\mathcal{P}(X)}B(\nu).
\end{align*}
Then does $\alpha=\beta$ always hold? If not, does it at least hold for $X$ separable?

This is a follow up question of [Does every connected compact metric space have a unique always attainable average distance?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4468488/does-every-connected-compact-metric-space-have-a-unique-always-attainable-averag) There it was shown in the answer that $\alpha=\beta$ for $X$ compact by a minimax theorem. This got me curious whether I could find a non-compact metric space for which $\alpha<\beta$.

Note that $0\leq\alpha\leq\beta<\infty$ for $X$ bounded. For $X$ unbounded, consider $x\in X$ and a sequence $x_1,x_2,\ldots\in X$ with $d(x,x_i)>2^i$. Take $\mu=\sum_{i\geq1}2^{-i}\delta_{x_i}$, such that $d(\mu,\nu)=\infty$ for all $\nu\in\mathcal{P}(X)$. It follows that $\alpha=\beta=\infty$. For $X$ totally bounded, its completion is compact, and thus $\alpha=\beta$. So any counterexample has to be bounded, but not totally bounded.

The reason I suspect the separable case to be easier is that then the space is strongly Lindelöf, which makes measures and their support behave much more intuitively. For example, a measure may have empty support, but only if $X$ is non-separable. However, I was not even able to come up with a counterexample for non-separable spaces. Part of this is due to the fact that it is very difficult to construct these pathological measures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question!

No, not even for separable metric spaces; in fact, the below counterexample is on a countable set of points.

The construction is as follows. We start with one point (the top, in the picture). At any given stage (there are $4$ or $5$ depicted below, depending on how you count), we proceed to the next stage by adding/appending two points at distance $2/3$ (say) from each other, with one point being at distance $1/2$ from all the previous points, and the other at distance $1$ from all the previous points.

So, in the picture below, red denotes distance $1/2$, green denotes distance $2/3$, and blue denotes distance $1$. We chose these numbers so that, defining the distance between a point and itself to be $0$, we (don't have to worry about the triangle inequality and thus) obtain a metric space.

[image]

Now, we claim $\alpha = 1/2$ and $\beta = 1$.

Indeed, for any given $\mu \in \mathcal{P}(X)$ and $\epsilon > 0$, we can choose finite $X' \subseteq X$ so that $\mu(X') \ge 1-\epsilon$ and let $\nu$ be the delta mass at any point that has distance $1/2$ to every point of $X'$, to see that $\alpha \le (1-\epsilon)\cdot \frac{1}{2}+\epsilon \cdot 1 = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

And similarly, given any $\nu \in \mathcal{P}(X)$ and $\epsilon > 0$, we can choose finite $X' \subseteq X$ so that $\nu(X') \ge 1-\epsilon$ and let $\mu$ be the delta mass at any point that has distance $1$ to every point of $X'$, to see that $\beta \ge (1-\epsilon)\cdot 1 + \epsilon \cdot 0 = 1-\epsilon$.

Comment: Nice counterexample! Just a small addendum since you only proved $\alpha\leq1/2$ and $\beta\geq1$: To get $A(\mu)=1/2$, we can take the average distance to two points on the right, and to get $B(\mu)=1$, we can take any singular point.

Comment: @SmileyCraft Thanks. I'm not sure I understand your comment though. For example, indeed only $\beta \ge 1$ was proven, but we trivially have $\beta \le 1$, and I don't think we could ever have $B(\mu) = 1$.

Comment: While $\beta\leq1$ is indeed trivial, you do in fact have $B(\mu)=1$ for $\mu$ any deterministic point. Take for $\nu$ any other deterministic point with distance $1$ to the point of $\mu$ to get $B(\mu)\geq d(\mu,\nu)=1$. Again $B(\mu)\leq1$ is trivial, so in a way this proof is redundant, but it does show $B(\mu)=1$ does occur.

For $\mu$ the average distance to two distinct points $a,b$ on the right, we have $d(\mu,c)\geq1/2$ for any $c\not\in\{a,b\}$ trivially. Furthermore $d(\mu,a)=d(\mu,b)=1/2$, so indeed $A(\mu)=1/2$.

Comment: @SmileyCraft Ok, I got confused, because showing that "$B(\mu) = 1$ does occur" does not imply $\beta = 1$, since $\beta$ is defined by an infimum. You are right  that taking $\mu$ as you described (avg of $a,b$) yields $A(\mu) = 1/2$, and in this case, finishes the proof that $A(\mu) = 1/2$.

Comment: Showing $B(\mu)=1$ occurs proves $\beta\leq1$, and since you already proved $\beta\geq1$, that shows $\beta=1$. But in fact, I just noticed that $B(\mu)=1$ for all $\mu\in\mathcal{P}(X)$. Indeed, you showed $\beta\geq1$ by showing $B(\mu)\geq1$ for all $\mu\in\mathcal{P}$, and $B(\mu)\leq1$ is again trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment.

There is a large literature on this sort of problem in which "unique always attainable average distance" of a metric space is referred to as its "rendezvous number". A proof of the existence of a rendezvous number for every connected compact metric spaces was first published in [this paper](https://www.rand.org/pubs/papers/P2298.html) by Oliver Gross in 1961.  In [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2589438), the common value of your $\ \alpha\ $ and $\ \beta\ $, when they're equal, is called a "weak rendezvous number". It's not difficult to construct examples which have a weak rendezvous number but no rendezvous number, and the paper gives one.

One possible approach to answering your question might be to start from an optimisation problem with a [duality gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_gap).